# Join Table with the same table only once based on some case

Tags: sql-server

I want to join documents from the table below with their parent document based on `NodeID = NodeParentID`. I want to join document only once with a parent that fits the best.

Following are the rules to select the best parent:

1. Parent document is in the same culture
2. Parent document is in the default culture (en-US in this case)
3. Select parent document with the lowest ID

[image: Document table]

According the rules above, this should be the output

[image: expected output]

But with my query

```
SELECT *
FROM Document as Child
LEFT JOIN Document AS Parent 
ON 
    CASE 
    WHEN Child.Culture = Parent.Culture THEN Parent.NodeID
    WHEN Parent.Culture = 'en-US' THEN Parent.NodeID
    ELSE (SELECT MIN(NodeID) FROM Document WHERE NodeID = Parent.NodeID)
    END = Child.NodeParentID
WHERE Child.AliasPath like '/Home/%'
AND Child.Level = 2
Order by Child.ID, Child.NodeID
```

I get all the combinations

[image: My result]

Here is the schema creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE Document
    ([ID] int, [NodeID] int, [NodeParentID] int, [Level] int, [AliasPath] varchar(49), [Culture] varchar(5));

INSERT INTO Document
    ([ID], [NodeID], [NodeParentID], [Level], [AliasPath], [Culture])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 0, 0, '/', 'en-US'),
    (2, 2, 1, 1, '/Home', 'en-US'),
    (3, 3, 1, 1, '/Contact', 'en-US'),
    (6, 3, 1, 1, '/Contact', 'sk-SK'),
    (13, 2, 1, 1, '/Home', 'it-IT'),
    (15, 2, 1, 1, '/Home', 'cs-CZ'),
    (16, 2, 1, 1, '/Home', 'sk-SK'),
    (4, 4, 2, 2, '/Home/English', 'en-US'),
    (5, 4, 2, 2, '/Home/English', 'it-IT'),
    (10, 8, 3, 2, '/Contact/Person', 'cs-CZ'),
    (11, 8, 3, 2, '/Contact/Person', 'it-IT'),
    (7, 5, 4, 3, '/Home/English/Slovak', 'sk-SK'),
    (14, 5, 4, 3, '/Home/English/Slovak', 'en-US'),
    (8, 6, 5, 4, '/Home/English/Slovak/Italian', 'it-IT'),
    (9, 7, 6, 5, '/Home/English/Slovak/Italian/Czech', 'cs-CZ'),
    (12, 9, 8, 3, '/Contact/Person/Slovakian', 'sk-SK');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an outer apply to find the best match of the parent. I wrote the subquery in the outer apply to get all the parents of the node, but then apply your rules in the order by so that we find the best match. By using `OUTER APPLY`, you will return the nodes whether any parents are found or not. If you wish to exclude children without parents (your root nodes), you can change to `CROSS APPLY`.

```
SELECT *
FROM Document C
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM Document
        WHERE C.NodeParentID = NodeID
        ORDER BY
            CASE WHEN Culture = C.Culture THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
            CASE WHEN Culture = 'en-US' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
            NodeId
    ) P
WHERE C.AliasPath like '/Home/%'
AND C.Level = 2
```

This results in your desired output.